# Numeric Up Down Control - Resizing the buttons while maintaining a fixed control size

Tags: vb.net-2010

did not think when I started this endevour that I would have to go past Google but here I am.  I am making a program for a family member that will run off his TV becuase he is practically Blind.  The Application requires a few NUD controls which I have placed on the form and sized accordingly.  The Problem is the little UP Down buttons are just like little slivers to him...Is there a way to keep my NUD control the size that it is but at the very least increase my button width on the control...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but it would be fairly simple to build your own custom control which contained a text box and two buttons, the button clicks would read the value in the text box, Parse it to and it, then increment or decrement.  You would just need to define these properties:

- Textbox - anchor left & top
- Up Button - anchor right & top
- Down Button - anchor right & bottom
- Resize method - catch it and set the heights of the buttons to the controls height / 2
- Define a ButtonWidth property; in the setter set the width of the buttons to the value, set the textbox width to the control width minus this value

I haven't tested this, so I'm not positive this will work correctly with the ANCHOR properties set; if not, just set anchor to NONE and manually set top, left, height, and width of each control on the control's RESIZE (and your ButtonWidth) properties.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am gonna give that a go...wow I am stupid for not thinking of that